# Loop through multidimensional array from AJAX with jquery to populate select

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, loops, fill

A multidimensional returned from php, here is my php array:

```
$brands = array("Bmw" => "200" ,"Mercedes" => "201", "Audi" => "202");
```

When the data is returnend how can I populate a select with this info?

Lets assume that I need fill a select with Brands and their ID.

```
<select>
  <option value="200">Bmw</option>
  <option value="201">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="202">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I dont know how to loop through the returned array to fill the select.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't know what AJAX have to do here... Is your $brands sent to your ajax response in JSON, HTML or whatever format? Need to see the ajax call

Comment: I send the data back from the PHP with json_encode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it this way.

```
$brands = array("Bmw" => "200" ,"Mercedes" => "201", "Audi" => "202");
$output = "<select>";
foreach($brands as $keys => $val){
    $output .= '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$keys.'</option>';
}
$output .= "</select>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: I cant do that, i have to wait 5min :D